# exporting blockchain from a specific block number

Tags: go-ethereum, export

is there an option for the export command in geth to export from only a specific blocknumber?  For example if I wanted to export the blockchain but only up to before the DAO attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore#blockchain-importexport):

> Or if you want to back up portions of the chain over time, a first and last block can be specified.
>   For example, to back up the first epoch:
>
> `geth export <filename> 0 29999`